# Convert theme to be based on Bootstrap?

Tags: themes, twitter-bootstrap

I have a theme that i would like to be based on the bootstrap grid instead of its original one and I'm in doubt if this is relatively easy to change or I will have unforeseen challenges.
So my question is what should be done in order to change the theme?

Is it as easy as just enqueuing the scripts(bootstrap stylesheet before the themes stylesheet) and changing the class and IDs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created at least two wordpress themes using Bootstrap 3. In fact, is not complicated at all. Besides the obvious, you need keep in mind three things to do:

- Enqueuing correctly both the bootstrap styles and scripts
- Set up an own "Walker Nav Menu" that override the default walker for create drop-down menus
- Change some elements with hooks like: search form (get_search_form), excerpt more (excerpt_more), default menu classes (nav_menu_css_class), and so on.

And that's it, at least that you should do.

Some examples:
http://gelatinisima.com
http://www.filos.unam.mx

Answer (score 0):

You can't just tweak a few things and expect your theme to work with Bootstrap. Converting to Bootstrap could be relatively simple, or very complex, depending on how your existing theme is built, and how complex it is. But there's no way we can give generic instructions, as it all depends on the theme.

Answer (score -1):

First you need put all bootstrap css rules into your template header.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ); ?>/css/bootstrap.css" media="screen, print, projection" />

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

Basicaly you need wrap your existing html markup with bootstarp, but need to look, if there a existing html elements, css classies is fixed width. On inner elements you dont need a fixed width, like a .content .new_item {width:500px;}, that will be wrong and breake your bootstarp wrapping.

Then you need make a grid layout based for example:

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span12">
        <div class="span4">4 columns</div>
        <div class="span4">4 columns</div>
        <div class="span4">4 columns</div>
        <div class="span4">4 columns</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="span8">
        12 - 4 = 8
        </div>
        <div class="span4">
        12 - 8 = 4
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

For more information you can check a grid html markup on bootstrap: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: You need enqueuing correctly the bootstrap styles

Comment: I always put it on manualy :) for better code changes and no conflict staff

Comment: But is not the standard way: http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-properly-add-javascripts-and-styles-in-wordpress/